# Merge/synonym-ise centura and guptateamdeveloper tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I just had a [centura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centura) tag wiki edit come up while going through the suggested edits queue. The pending edit says that [centura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centura) is the old name for something called Team Developer, which has it's own tag: [guptateamdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guptateamdeveloper).

I looked at the questions for each tag, [centura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centura) has 9 questions and [guptateamdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guptateamdeveloper) has 14, but 6 questions are common to both tags.

I don't think there is any reason to have both tags, and I thought making [centura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centura) a synonym for [guptateamdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guptateamdeveloper), but there is only 1 user with answer score more than 5 on each tag, so I don't think a vote could ever be passed.

What should I have done in this case, and what should be done about these tags?

Comment: Burn [centura] seems like the logical thing. 9 questions on a now replaced system.

Comment: Burn both are replace with [gupta-team-developer], for everyone's sanity!